# Probability, making a selection of 2 people from 50, with conditions

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A president and a treasurer are to be chosen from a club consisting of 50 people. How many different choices of officers are possible if 
A will serve only if he is president; 
B and C will serve together or not at all; 
D and E will not serve together?
I need to construct its tree diagram and find total number of ways of selection with given constraints.

Answer (score 1):

You construct the tree by deciding how many ways there are to fill the president position, and *for each distinct way*, how many ways there are to fill the treasurer position, based on who is willing and acceptable.

- If A is president, who can serve as treasurer?

  - Only B and C will not serve as treasurer if A is president
  - Thus there are $47$ people who are willing and acceptable to serve as treasurer when A is president.
- If B or C is president, who can serve as treasurer?

  - ...
- If D or E is president, who can serve as treasurer?

  - ...
- If any of the $45$ other people are president, who can serve to be treasurer?

  - ...

$$1\times 47 + 2 \times \underline\quad + 2\times \underline\quad + 45 \times \underline\quad$$

Fill in the blanks.

Comment: no its more like
if A will only serve if he is president otherwise he wont serve.
B and C will only serve together
d and e wont serve together
now taking all these conditions into consideration i have to make a tree diagram and calculate total number of ways to select officers

Comment: @Farhan.  That's the point. You construct the tree by deciding how many ways there are to fill the president position, and *for each distinct way*, how many ways there are to fill the treasurer position.  **For instance:** if $A$ is president, there are $47$ ways to fill the treasurer position as only $B$ and $C$ won't accept the treasurer position.